# HTML & CSS & JS error

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<script src='script.js'></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I have all this code, and it's all linked up as you can see in the code. But for some reason, it doesn't work unless I use style and script tags within the HTML. Why is this and how would I fix it?
This is all in a folder on my computer. I plan to upload it to the web later.

Comment: Nope. All good.

Comment: Not enough information. Are you running this from a server? Just opening it from a folder in your computer? Are all files in the same folder? Please edit the question with those details.

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: Your script runs before your content is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a folder which contain this file 3- index.html , style.css, and script.js 
**So basically you need to shift your script.js before body tag**
**CHECK THE HTML STRUCTURE BELOW** ADDITIONALLY You can add the latest compiled jQuery

```js
//your script.js structure- 

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/*IN YOUR STYLE.CSS */


/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--in your index.html structure like-->
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script><!-- ADDITIONALLY YOU CAN ADD THIS.. But RIGHT NOW Modal WILL RUN WITHOUT THIS--> 
<script src='script.js'></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<script src='script.js'></script>` before your `</body>` tag.

It seems that you are executing your JS script that depends on DOM elements script before their are loaded